# Error in kotlin flow doesn't trigger catch in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

With migration to `kotlin`, `view model` and recent changes in [kotlin test lib][1] I am working on issue with test.

I have a scenario:

1. request a web resource asynchronously
2. in case of error put the request in cache and update state with new pending request

All of this with help of `kotlin flow` and `view model`.

Scenario works well when executes on emulator, but fails when I run test for it. The issue is catch block of `flow` has not been triggered when error has thrown in `flow`.

Here is the code:

```
   fun mintToken(to: String, value: Value, uri: String) {
        logger.d("[start] mintToken()")
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.mintToken(to, value, uri)
                .catch { it ->
                    if (it is TransactionException
                        && it.message!!.contains("Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction")) {
                        cacheRepository.createChainTx(to, value, uri) // TODO consider always put in pending cache and remove after it confirms as succeeded
                        val txReceipt = TransactionReceipt()
                        txReceipt.transactionHash = ""
                        emit(Response.Data(txReceipt))
                    } else {
                        emit(Response.Error.Exception(it))
                    }
                }
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect {
                    logger.d(it.toString())
                    when (it) {
                        is Response.Data -> {
                            if (it.data.transactionHash.isEmpty()) {
                                state.update {
                                    it.copy(
                                        status = Status.MINT_TOKEN,
                                        pendingTx = it.pendingTx + Transaction(to, value, uri)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        is Response.Error.Message -> {
                            val errorMsg = "Something went wrong on mint a token with error ${it.msg}"
                            logger.d(errorMsg)
                            state.update {
                                val newErrors = it.errors + "Something went wrong on mint a token with error ${errorMsg}"
                                it.copy(status = Status.MINT_TOKEN, errors = newErrors)
                            }
                        }
                        is Response.Error.Exception -> {
                            logger.e("Something went wrong on mint a token ${to}, ${value}, ${uri}", it.error)
                            state.update {
                                val newErrors = it.errors + "Something went wrong on mint a token ${to}, ${value}, ${uri}"
                                it.copy(status = Status.MINT_TOKEN, errors = newErrors)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        logger.d("[end] mintToken()")
    }
```

```
    @Throws(TransactionException::class)
    override fun mintToken(to: String, value: Value, uri: String): Flow<Response<TransactionReceipt>> {
        return flow {
            throw TransactionException(
                "Transaction receipt was not generated after 600 seconds for transaction",
                "")
        }
    }
```

Test code for this is:

```
    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    // Set the main coroutines dispatcher for unit testing.
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private lateinit var subj: WalletViewModel

    @Test
    fun `when mintToken() is called with correct values, timeout exception is returned and pending tx are updated with new value`() = runTest {
        val to = "0x6f1d841afce211dAead45e6109895c20f8ee92f0"
        val url = "https://google.com"
        val testValue = Value(
            "Software Development",
            BigInteger.valueOf(1000L),
            BigInteger.valueOf(2000L),
            false,
            BigInteger.valueOf(0)
        )

        subj.mintToken(to, testValue, url)

        assertThat(
            "There is no pending transaction after mint a new token with timeout error",
            subj.uiState.value.pendingTx.isNotEmpty()
        )
    }
```

Test code differs from dev code by replacing `dispatcher` in `MainCoroutineRule` and using kotlin construction `runTest {}`. How does it affect this case? Does issue case lays in some other place?
[1]: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-test/MIGRATION.md

Comment: Running into the same thing. I believe it has to do with the way that the unit test framework is designed to suppress/swallow exceptions, minus the ones that the test is looking to be thrown (using assertThrows). Did you find a work around @Joe Dow?